# Create a webpack libraryTarget that produces function body

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I'd like to have webpack output code as if it was a javascript function body, and use the return value to expose the library.

I've created this plugin (modelled on the internal webpack implementations e.g. SetVarMainTemplatePlugin):

```
const ConcatSource = require("webpack-sources").ConcatSource;

class returnPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.plugin("this-compilation", (compilation) => {
            const mainTemplate = compilation.mainTemplate;

            compilation.templatesPlugin("render-with-entry", (source, chunk, hash) => {
                mainTemplate.applyPluginsWaterfall("asset-path", "return", {
                    hash: hash,
                    chunk: chunk
                });
                return new ConcatSource('return ', source);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This does generate an output file with `return` prefixed, however it seems to fail some final pass, and webpack errors out with:

> ERROR in unknown: 'return' outside of function (1:0)

Should I be using something other than `ConcatSource`?